# Lost gtk theme style in login screen after Compiz crashed

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

Normally, all controls in login screen (button, textbox, etc..) have the current gtk-theme style. But after Compiz crashed (always happen when I enable or disable a plugin), the style has gone (no more transparent button, rounder textbox, or my current icon theme), instead there are ugly Windows-95-like buttons, textbox and unknown-theme icon.

Is this a Compiz bug? How could I fix it?

PS: Im on Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity).

This is my Ubuntu login screen:

[image: The textbox and button are squared]

[image]

This is the default Ubuntu login screen:

[image]

[image]

I'm on Dell Vostro 1540 with Intel HD 3000 VGA. At first, my login screen looks nothing wrong. But after Compiz crashed (when I enable or disable any plugin), the login screen looks like the above pictures. So, I don't think my graphics card is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem with unity.I guess that is a problem with your graphics card.Compiz has [problems supporting the 82G965 Chipset](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/148247).

You can try to revive the menubar's look with the following command:

```
killall gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-settings-daemon &
```

On the other hand,try to login from the Ubuntu Classic Session,then install Unity 2D and then login again from the Unity 2D Session.

Comment: I tried it but had no luck. Do I need to re-install LightDM? How to do that?

Comment: Maybe you do not have that graphics card.What is your graphics card model and chipset anyway?

Comment: Im on Dell Vostro 1540 with Intel HD 3000 VGA. At first, my login screen looks nothing wrong. But after compiz crashed (when I enable or disable any plugin), the login screen looks like the above pictures. So, I dont think my graphics card is the problem.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html

Comment: I tried to add 20 seconds before running gnome-settings-daemon but had no luck. It just delayed 20s, then show my desktop. But nothing change in login screen.

Comment: Wait a second...does that effect happen only at your login screen?when you login,is the theme normal?

Comment: GTK3 theme is fine. Problem only happens at login screen.